# Access a protected method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have to the following protected method in my color class and i can't access it in my MSTest Test Project(.NET Core) class how can i get access to this method?

I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I can't change any of the class definitions.

I have tried using `PrivateObject` and that didn't work....

> "The type or namespace 'PrivateObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
public class Color : Shape {
    protected override IEnumerable<string> GetSizes(string name){
        //do stuff    
    }
}
```

Comment: You could test a method that's _not_ protected but calls the protected one, since unit tests aren't supposed to dig into the implementation, only verify the _public_ behavior.

Comment: OP, you said you tried `PrivateObject`.  Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: my best piece of advice is to redesign your classes in such way that you only need to test the public API of every class. if you didn't wanted to make a method public you can still test the protected internal methods.

Comment: OP, please refrain from duplicating your questions.  If you edit your previous question and comment why the proposed solution wasn't what you needed, that question will be moved to the top of the question queue and will probably show up on the front page, earning it a fresh look from more programmers.

Comment: I tried PrivateObject color = new PrivateObject(new Color()); but it says "The type or namespace 'PrivateObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Golfer1145 Yes, I see that in your previous question, which has an answer.

Comment: Those answers also didn't work

Comment: @Golfer1145 Then write a comment on the answer explaining why. Or edit the question like I suggested.  Duplicating your question is not the appropriate solution here.  They took time out of their very important day to help you, and you didn't provide them *any* feedback to help guide each other to a working solution?

Comment: here you can find the namespace of PrivateObject. or you could have just pressed `ctrl+.` in your visual studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject?view=mstest-net-1.2.0

Comment: @Bizhan That class doesn't exist in .Net Core.  https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/366

Comment: i didn't notice net core in your question, here is the closed issue https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/366

Comment: Just make the method `protected internal override ...` and friend your test assembly by adding [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Your.Test.Assembly")] into the project's `AssemblyInfo.cs` where your class is declared.